# ImeOptions button does not change for EditTexts with inputTypes of password

Tags: java, android

I needed to assign the action button while in password field, to login. Here is what I tried:

XML:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/password"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/ui_password_hint"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:typeface="normal"
     android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>
```

Java:

```
 etPassword = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.password);
 etPassword.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
 etPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
 etPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

 @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            ((LandingActivity) getActivity()).DoLogin(etUsername.getText().toString(),etPassword.getText().toString(),cbRemember.isChecked());
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
```

But it still shows the new line button as action. How do I fix it?

PS: My other imeOptions are working in my other EditTexts which are not password fields. I only have problem with this password EditText.

Edit:
So the problem is setting the inputType to password programatically. When I set it to password in xml, it did work. However I need to set it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Change `maxlines =1` to `singleLine = true`. may it helps
    here is my code i am using same field

```
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                style="@style/inputFieldStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: Tried that, it didnt work. The problem is not wth linecount, it is with inputType = password.

Comment: So the problem is setting the inputType  to password programatically. When I set it to password in xml, it did work. However I need to set it programatically.

Comment: etPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());